# SequelizeEagerLoadingError: Role is not associated to User

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js, associations

I am using Sequelize with MYSQL and express.
I am getting  **SequelizeEagerLoadingError: Role is not associated to User** when trying to select data from related models using include.

I am having two models, User and Role. A user belongsToMany Roles through RoleUser and a Role belongsToMany users through RoleUser. Here are my models:

**//User Model**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    id: {type:DataTypes.UUID,allowNull:false,unique:true,primaryKey:true},
    UserName: {type:DataTypes.STRING,unique:true,allowNull:false},
     Email: {type:DataTypes.STRING,allowNull:false,unique:true,validate: { isEmail: {msg: "Invalid Email"} }},
    Password: {type:DataTypes.STRING,allowNull:false},

  }, {});
  User.associate = function(models) {


        User.belongsToMany(models.Role,
            {
        through: 'RoleUser',
        foreignkey:'UserId'

    })




 };
  return User;
};

//Role Model
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Role = sequelize.define('Role', {
    id: {type:DataTypes.UUID,allowNull:false,unique:true,primaryKey:true},
    Name: DataTypes.STRING,
    Description: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  Role.associate = function(models) {
    Role.belongsToMany(models.User,
        {
            through:'RoleUser',
            foreignKey:'RoleId'

        }),


  };
  return Role;
};

//My query on user model

xports.index = function(req, res) {
  return User.findAll({ 
          include: [{
          model: Role,

        }],

    attributes:{
        exclude: ['Password','createdAt','updatedAt']

    }}).then((users)=>{
    console.log(users)
    }).catch(error=>{
    console.log(error);
    })
```

**//ERROR**

```
 SequelizeEagerLoadingError: Role is not associated to User!

 **STATUS CODE: 200(OK)**

 I am getting same error in other models in the entire project. According to me the associations is correctly established and I can see in the PHPMyAdmin Relation View.

 *Express Version: 4.16.4
 Sequelize Version: 4.31.2
 Mysql2 version: 1.6.1*

 Any help. What am I doing wrong.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you need to specify how are you gonna call the include.

```
User.associate = function(models) {
  User.belongsToMany(models.Role,{
    through: 'RoleUser',
    foreignkey:'UserId',
    as: 'Roles'
  })
};
```

You need to do the other way arroud from roles to users if you need that, and with any other association. Then on your query:

```
User.findAll({ 
  include: [{
    model: Role,
    as: 'Roles'
  }],
  attributes:{ exclude: ['Password','createdAt','updatedAt'] }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to assist me. But I am still getting exactly same error. My associations looks fine but its just not working for me.

Comment: @wafutech I'm having the same problem...how did you solve it? best